# Find control in Dataset

Tags: vb.net, gridview, dataset

I have this code so I can grab the values ind the dataset before i bind it.
can't get the dirctcast to work

```
       dim ds as new dataset("Mytable")
       gridView.DataSource = ds

            Dim dataRow As DataRowView = DirectCast(ds.Tables.Item("MyTable").Rows(), DataRowView)
            Dim ID_Equipamento As String = dataRow("ID_Equipamento").ToString()
            Dim ID_Password = dataRow("ID_Password").ToString()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use VB, but will give it a go anyways;

ds.Tables.Item("MyTable").Rows() gives you a data row collection which is not a DataRowView.

Use this instead;

```
 Dim dataRow As DataRow = ds.Tables.Item("MyTable").Rows().Item(0)
```

Also I see you call the dataset Mytable. A dataset is a container of datatables, so I recommend calling it MyDataSet. You then add a dataTable - for example MyTable.

Cheers!